# CKEditor: Buttons and Text Area Disabled has been updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

OK, so I was playing with installing SCALD (in  Drupal) and I think I have that figured out, but I cannot test it until I get CKEditor working again. Currently, the CKEditor's UI is showing, but all of the buttons are disabled and there are no related JS errors. This whole process is really holding me up! Grrrrr!!

**Using:**

Drupal:

- Drupal 7.5.1
- JQuery Update 7.x-2.7 (dev version with with jquery migrate) with jQuery v1.10.2
- CKEditor 7.x-7.17 (JQuery library 4.5.11)

All SCALD related modules are disabled

Testing Browsers:

- Firefox 49.0.1
- IE - Edge 38.14393.0.0
- Chrome 53.0.2785.143 m

**plugins:** I have already tried removing all of the files for the plugins and that did not change anything

**CKEditor Global Profile Settings**

- Path to CKEditor: %m/ckeditor - /sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor
- Local Path to CKEditor: ./sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor
- Path to Plugins Directory: /sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins
- Aggregate: Disabled
- Use Toolbar Drag and Drop: enabled

**Profile Settings:**

Security: I do not have any of these modules installed so all that is there is 'plain text' and 'Always run security filters'

Editor Appearance:

- Toolbar State on Startup: expanded
- Default Editor State: Enabled
- Show the disable/enable rich text editor...): disabled

editor is white there: Hmmmm... javascript gives me this error"

```
TypeError: b is undefined
.init()
ckeditor.js:833 A/< /<()
ckeditor.js:251 CKEDITOR.scriptLoader< /<.load/e()
ckeditor.js:231 CKEDITOR.scriptLoader< /<.load/A()
ckeditor.js:231 CKEDITOR.scriptLoader< /<.load/r()
ckeditor.js:231 CKEDITOR.scriptLoader< /<.load/x/e.$.onload/<() ckeditor.js:232
```

File Browser Settings: (have not purchased CKFinder)
File Browser Type: none
File Browser Type (image): same as in the link dialog
File Browser Type (flash): same as in the link dialog

Besides that javascript error on a setup page, any thoughts on this? It looks like it is setup correctly.Any thoughts about the javascript error on the settings page?

Answer (score 0):

I performed the following:

- disabled the module
- uninstalled the module
- deleted module directory
- installed dev version
- reconfigured editors
- uploaded widget plugin for SCALD

Editors are there =O
Perhaps it ended up just resetting the CKEditor settings to default.

Comment: bro could you please take a look at my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397155/ckedtior-appearance-not-show-fully-in-drupal-7 ?